# Can I use Webpack and ASP.NET Core on one port?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack-dev-server

I created project ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 + Webpack and configurated to run ASP.NET Core and Webpack dev server on one port. But when I try call api ASP.NET Core I see loading angular 2 app. Can I use on one port or I must configure different ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work fine if you run as one process. You may have some problem with configuration/routing. Without code sources it is difficult to say what is wrong...

You may use one of those project templates on github to catch your mistake:

- [aspnetcore-angular2-universal](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal)
- [Angular2WebpackVisualStudio](https://github.com/damienbod/Angular2WebpackVisualStudio)

Comment: aspnetcore-angular2-universal don't work and Angular2WebpackVisualStudio work with different port

Comment: @Greg aspnetcore-angular2-universal may not work without last node. It work for me with v6.9.4

Comment: Yes, I'm it understood